# Somehow owner of SQLite database reverts to root

Tags: linux, apache, sqlite, apache2

I have a helloWorld SQLite database file, "helloWorld.db" and use Apache2 as a web server.

My login account is "root", I update its owner to www-data by the following command:

> chown www-data:www-data helloWorld.db

And it works:

> -rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data  www-data 1806336 Nov 13 14:43 helloWorld.db

But somehow it will revert to root after a while and cause the DB cannot be accessed:

> -rwxr-xr-x  1 root      root     1806336 Nov 13 15:03 kaser_playit.db

Even using Git to track the helloWorld.db, there is no diff after changed the DB's owner and permission.

What should I do to keep the owner and permission of the DB to www-data:www-data?

Comment: Simple. Don't login as root.

Comment: But why the file would change owner after changing git branch?